# Delete command or "trigger word" message

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a message I want our bot to send but, in order to keep the chat clean, I'd like to delete the message that invoked the command: how can I do this?
This is the current code for the message:

```js
if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("<@botsnumberidhere> what are the numbers")) {
  message.channel.send("This is good, real good.", {
    file: "https://domainforimage.com/image0.jpg" // Or replace with FileOptions object
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the message with [`Message.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete). Please note that this will tell Discord that you want to delete the message, but you'll still be able to access the properties of the `message` variable you previously stored.

```js
if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("<@botsnumberidhere> what are the numbers")) {
  message.delete(); // You can put it here.
  message.channel.send("This is good, real good.", {
    file: "https://domainforimage.com/image0.jpg"
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So this will delete the person/user message who asked the question, correct?

Comment: Exactly: it will delete the message with `""<@botsnumberidhere> what are the numbers""`, the one that triggered the command

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Do you happen to know how to make a link to a channel as well, just like the mention? I have the Channel ID but not sure how to implement it.

Comment: You can do it two ways: you can either write directly `<#channelIdHere>` or get the channel object and concatenate it with a string. If my answer helped you, please accept it (tick on the left) so that the question is marked as resolved. You can also upvote if feel to. For more info about how to accept an answer, see [this post on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)